# Splitting one large file into many if the text in a column doesn't match the text in the one before it

Tags: python-3.x, csv, awk, sed

I searched for awhile and couldn't find a response to this. I have a standard tsv file with the following format:

```
1    100    101    350    A
1    101    102    300    A
1    102    103    180    A
1    800    801    60     B
1    801    802    70     B
1    802    803    82     B
1    975    976    105    C
1    976    977    108    C
```

etc. This goes on for a few million lines and there are 1000 different regions in column 5 (A,B,C). The regions are all different sizes in terms of number of lines. I would like to iterate over the file and split each region into its own file.

FileA.txt

```
1    100    101    350    A
1    101    102    300    A
1    102    103    180    A
```

FileB.txt

```
1    800    801    60     B
1    801    802    70     B
1    802    803    82     B
```

FileC.txt

```
1    975    976    105    C
1    976    977    108    C
```

Comment: Given the tags you've added - it does look like you're looking for a solution for anyone to just provide code. However, have you tried anything in those languages or tools and found anything out that does / doesn't work kind of thing?

Comment: Assuming you want python. Are the labels always on char long?

Comment: Did you explore `csplit`?  See this post: [splitting textfiles according to a regular expression](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15662/201820).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: @jww Did you downvote all answers?

Comment: @MegaIng yes he did. He does that every time he leaves that comment or any other negative comment about the question. I'm upvoting them all again now to compensate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With awk

```
awk '{out = "File" $NF ".txt"; print >> out; close(out)}' file
```

More efficient, not closing the destination file after every line:

```
awk '
    $NF != dest {if (out) close(out); dest = $NF; out = "File" dest ".txt"} 
    {print >> out}
' file
```

Comment: 1000 open files in not a problem on most systems, so `{ print > "File" $NF }` should be enough

Comment: True. This is relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36841/4667 -- for my system `ulimit -n` is 1024, so 1000 is pretty close.

Comment: and: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html

Comment: You can actually just write `close(out)` instead of `if (out) close(out)` since passing a null string to close() or trying to close a file that wasn't opened by redirection is a no-op and close() will just return success. I'd upvote it for real if I hadn't already used my upvote on every answer to compensate for @jww having downvoted them all!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small solution in python using `groupby` and `str.rpartition`:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open("in_file.txt") as f_in:
for name,lines in groupby(f_in.readlines(),key=lambda x:x.rpartition(" ")[2].strip()):
        with open(f"out_{name}.txt","w") as f_out:
            f_out.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Thanks, the label is variable length. The awk solution below works great. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

So using grep, something like:

```
for L in `grep -oE '[A-Z]+$'|uniq|sort|uniq`
do
grep -E ${L}'$' > file.${L}.txt
done
```

The phrase `grep -oE '[A-Z]+$'|uniq|sort|uniq` should find all the unique keys, which you then use to re-parse the file multiple times. The sequence uniq|sort|uniq is to reduce the input to sort.

If you really need to do it in a single pass, then you could process each line, and append it immediately to the appropriate output file.

Comment: This is very inefficient especially since the input file is large and there are thousands of patterns to loop through.

Comment: Then do the second thing. That also has low memory overhead. Maybe I'll write that up.

Answer (score 1):

So the scripting single-pass low memory line-by-line approach:

```
while IFS=" " read -r value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 remainder
do
  echo $value1 $value2 $value3 $value4 $value5 $remainder >> output.${value5}.txt
done < "input.txt"
```

Of course, you need to ensure there are no pre-existing output files, but that can be achieved a number of ways efficiently.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the number of variables required, bash lets you read into an array: `while read -ra values; do ...` and then you can get the last field with `last=${values[-1]}`, or to get the 5th field `fifth=${values[4]}`

Comment: Indeed, though that depends on d_k's requirement. Both suffer that you lose the exact spacing layout of the columns, though I don't know if d_k cares about that. There are many refinements.

Comment: Indeed. You could do `IFS= read -r line; do [[ $line =~ ([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]*$ ]]; last=${BASH_REMATCH[1]` and now you have the line in its original form and the last field.